# Drush cannot find your database connection details

Tags: drush

I try to install open social using drush-8.3.0 and drupal-8.7.5. The first step is to run `composer create-project goalgorilla/social_template:dev-master public_html/peer/opensocial --no-interaction`. that works fine. The next step is `drush -y site-install social --db-url=mysql://root:root@db:3306/social` and results in the following error:

> Drush\Sql\SqlException: Unable to find a matching SQL Class. Drush cannot find your database connection details. in phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc:554

Using MySQL Wizerd and MySQL admin I have created the social database and defined username, password and ip address in `drush -y site-install social --db-url=mysql db_username db_password://root:root@IP address:3306/social`.

I have no ida how to find out what is realy going on? I am on a linux shared server. Can anybody help? Here is stack trace:

> #0 phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc(539): drush_sql_get_class(Array)
>
> #1 phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/commands/core/site_install.drush.inc(124): drush_sql_get_class()
>
> #2 phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_core_pre_site_install('social', '://root:root@10...')
>
> #3 phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
>
> #4 phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command('social', '://root:root@10...')
>
> #5 phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
>
> #6 phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(67): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
>
> #7 phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc(465): drush_main()
>
> #8 phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/includes/startup.inc(369): drush_run_main(false, '/', 'Phar detected. ...')
>
> #9 phar:///home/username/bin/drush/drush/drush(114): drush_startup(Array)
>
> #10 /home/username/bin/drush/drush(10): require('phar:///home/oi...')
>
> #11 {main}

when I run `drush @hpc.dev sql-conf` I get this:

> Scanning into /home/username/public_html/peer/opensocial/html/sites/default for /hpc.dev.alias.drush(8|)rc.php$/ [0.33 sec, 7.29 MB]                                                                                                          [debug] Could not find the alias @hpc.dev [0.33 sec, 7.29 MB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should really use Drush 9 or 10 - see https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#drupal-compatibility And install Drush site locally as described on the same page.

However, the message `Unable to find a matching SQL Class` probably means that shared server you are running Drush on is missing the needed PHP database extensions. This is typically PDO with MySQL (pdo_mysql and mysqli) - see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/php-requirements#database

A typically problem is that PHP in the web server has these extensions, but not PHP on the command line.

Comment: Yes your right those php's are not at the root level thank you for your help.